# How to convert Rails 2 / RSpec test to Rails 3 / RSpec 2 syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I am upgrading a rails 2 app to rails 3 & not sure how to "upgrade" the following line from one of my tests

```
Category.should_receive(:find).with(:all,:conditions => {:parent_id => @parent_id}, :order => 'disp_order DESC').and_return(@categories_collection)
```

Hoping someone can provide some pointers on this as I am not 100% sure where to start here.

I get the following error when I run this:

```
Failure/Error: Category.should_receive(:find).with(:all,
       (<Category(id: integer, permalink: string, name: string, parent_id: integer) (class)>).find(:all, {:conditions=>{:parent_id=>1}, :order=>"display_order DESC"})
```

****Update 1**

I am seeing something really strange now, I have refactored as Jim explained (great explanation btw!) but now get the following:

```
Failure/Error: Category.should_receive(:with_parent).with(1).and_return(@sub_category)
       (<Category(id: integer, permalink: string, name: string, parent_id: integer) (class)>).with_parent(1)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

However, if I add the following to my test:

```
puts Category.with_parent(1).length.to_s
```

the output is "1" - the correct / expected value. For some reason RSpec is not seeing this & throwing an error. Do you know why this might be happening?

****Update 2**

Ok, interestingly if I use the following my test passes:

```
Category.with_parent(@parent_id).should == [@sub_category]
```

while this fails:

```
Category.should_receive(:with_parent).with(@parent_id).and_return(@sub_category)
```

Is there a problem with using should_receive & .ad_return within this context in rspec2?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

From the line from your test, it seems like the code under test is:

```
Category.find(:all, :conditions => {:parent_id => @parent_id}, :order => 'disp_order DESC')
```

This syntax was deprecated in Rails 3 in favour of chainable AREL calls, so the same finder function would now be written as:

```
Category.where(:parent_id => @parent_id).order('disp_order DESC')
```

You can probably tell that mocking this is going to be harder because of the method chaining. Therefore the best advice is to refactor the finder into a method (perhaps using scope) on the Category class which can be isolated and mocked more easily.

For example:

```
class Category << ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :with_parent_id, lambda { |parent_id| where(:parent_id => parent_id).order('disp_order DESC') }

end
```

Then you can mock the finder call like this:

```
Category.should_receive(:with_parent_id).with(@parent_id).and_return(@categories_collection)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, added response to OP